# User Profile Synchronization currently not available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile-service

Our SharePoint farm suddenly failed to run the profiles sync.

I have checked the Log file and found below ULS Log snipped which is not certain to any error.

```
"The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileImportJob (ID ab1ad955-29d5-40ea-9f8c-40a9f1b7d8c9) threw an exception. More information is included below.

Generic failure"
```

**I have tried :**

1. Forefront Identity Manager Service and set the startup type to Automatic (Delayed Start).
2. I granted the Network Service account basic "Read & Execute/List folder contents/Read" permissions to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0 directory.

**Nothing worked. SharePoint Keep logging the same ERROR**

**Snippet from Event Viewer:**
[image]
**Snippet from CA User Profile Service application:**
[image]
**Snippet from CA Timer Job History:**
[image]

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Is your user profile sync service running? You can check via Central Admin, services on the server .

Comment: Yes FIM and FIM Sync services are running

Comment: Have you tried running PSConfig \ Restarting the server?

Comment: I cannot run PSConfig/ Restart  the server as it is live.. any other solution?

Comment: I am not using sync on my farms just import. In the past I had issue but it was relating to the sync service stopping, which you checked already. Have a look at this blog I used the steps in the past to troubleshoot: https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/30/user-profile-error/

Comment: If nothing from above will work I would raise emergency change for server restart. Your FE will still be served (well if you run your sync from APP server)

Comment: you can check pending reboot status with this https://github.com/bcwilhite/PendingReboot

Comment: Thank you marek for your suggestions.. I will try to restart after working hours.  Some people are suggesting User Profile Service / Timer and clear cache(while timer stopped). Will try these things and update here.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you could check is:

1. Go to CA > Application Management > manage services on server. Make sure that User profile service and User Profile sync service is running.
2. Application pool used by User Profile service Application in IIS.Make sure all are started
3. The application pool account should be a domain user. Ensure if anyone has changed the application pool account. Go to Central Administrator > Security > Configure Service Account > Select the application pool and check the account for it.

If above do not work, you can try the solutions in below article:

https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/30/user-profile-error/